# NSString isEqualTo packets not working?

Tags: objective-c, tcp

I have a python chat server and the iPhone is the client to the server.
I send a message to the Python server and the iPhone recieves it and NSLogs it out just fine. But if I use:

```
if ([output isEqualToString:@"hello"]) {
    NSLog(@"Hello!");
}
```

But it doesnt do anything (I have sent hello out in the chat). output is an `NSString` formatted like this:

```
NSStirng * output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I can NSLog it out fine, but I cannot use if statements with it.
Does anyone know a solution?
Thanks!

**Im new to packet programming so excuse my ignorance. Im using TCP packets by the way**

Answer (score 4):

I'm willing to bet that the `length` of "hello" is not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: Thats what they want us to believe!

Comment: NSString * output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; Is the correct one xD

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
 NSString * output =@"hardeep"; 


if ([output caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Hardeep"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}else
    NSLog(@"NO");
```